# Como desenvolver uma página inicial wordpress que mude conforme localidade

Tags: wordpress

Preciso criar um site, em wordpress, que a home reconheça a localização através de IP. Exemplo:

No Rio de Janeiro o IP é XXXXXX, nesse caso a página inicial seria X
Em São Paulo o IP é  yyyyyy, a página inicial seria outra, no caso Y

Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Não tem como. Faça igual os sites de telefonia, coloca uma modal perguntando o estado onde o usuário mora.

Comment: Tenta ver algo [assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52227/como-obter-localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-atual-do-usu%C3%A1rio-atrav%C3%A9s-da-api-do-google-maps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem como fazer sim. E pode ser feito tanto pela parte do cliente como pela parte do servidor.

Para isso você terá que dispor de um serviço de geolocalização, nesse caso eu usei o [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/) que oferece serviços tanto pagos como gratuitos com a limitação de 50,000 acessos mensais(se exemplo parar de funcionar será por conta desse limite).

Da parte do cliente o exemplo é simples, basta fazer uma requisição a `http://ipinfo.io` munida de callback que aceite um parâmetro que receberá o um JSON com as informações sobre a localização geográfica.

Nesse [link](https://ipinfo.io/developers) encontra-se as informações sobre a API do serviço `http://ipinfo.io`.

**Exemplo stand alone simulando a geolocalização no cliente em JavaScript**

```js
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (r) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + r.ip);
    $("#localização").html("Localização: " + r.city + ", " + r.region + ", " + r.country);    
}, "json");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="localização"></div>
```

Da parte do servidor o que muda é que ao invés de passar um callback o que vai ser informado é o endereço IP do cliente que armazenado em [`$_SERVER\['REMOTE_ADDR'\]`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) e a resposta deve ser decodificada em um array associativo por [`json_decode( string $json [, bool $assoc ] ) : mixed`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

**Exemplo do lado do servidor em PHP**

```php
<?php

  if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
     $r = json_decode ( 
        file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'?'), true
     );
     echo "Localização: " . $r['city'] . ", " . $r['region'] .  ", " . $r['country'];    
  } else {
     echo "Endereço IP não disponível para localização.";
  }

?>
```

Lembrando que da parte do servidor deve-se levar em conta que o cliente pode estar por trás de um proxy e seriam necessárias outras técnicas para detectar o proxy e obter o IP do cliente, técnicas essas que fogem ao escopo da questão.